# Receiving "end of script output before headers" error even though script works

Tags: python, html, xampp

I created a simple html page to post to python script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Name</h1>

<form action="/cgi-bin/ver1.py" method="get">
  <label for="fname">VIN</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="searchbox"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" formtarget="_blank">Submit to a new window/tab</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

the ver1.py looks like this:

```
#!C:\Python\python.exe


import requests
import webbrowser
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
 

vin=form.getvalue('searchbox')
token='withheld'

dr=requests.get("withheld" % (token, vin))




window_stkr=(dr.json()["car"]["sticker"]["pdf"])
webbrowser.open_new_tab(window_stkr)
```

It all works correctly, except for the part where instead of just opening one new tab with window_stkr it also opens a second tab with the

> end of script output before headers

error

when looking at the error log from apache, the only line there is following:

> [Fri Sep 11 00:46:21.231868 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 11624:tid 1896]
> [client ::1:54144] End of script output before headers: ver1.py,
> referer: http://localhost/decoder.html

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: every page/url/request should send response to browser - but you send nothing. You don't send even headers. And this can be your problem.

Comment: @furas there is no traceback, it's the only line that is generated after I enter the value in the box

Comment: in client-server when browser sends request (tries to connect with `url`) then server has to send response with page or at least with headers. And `ver1.py` should send some response to browser too - it can be even empty page but it will have headers with information for browser that page/url was accessed without problem  (status code 200). Or it should send response with information to redirect back to page with form.

Comment: How would I go about sending a response with information to redirect back to the page with form?

Comment: search in Stackoverflow: [Python CGI: How to redirect to another page after processing POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161149/python-cgi-how-to-redirect-to-another-page-after-processing-post-data) . You could even try to  send response with redirection to PDF - instead of using `webbrowser.open()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @furas pointed out it was because I was not sending any response back to the browser.

I made below changes and instead of 3 tabs, I now have one html page and the pdf opens in a window where the error used to be:

```
#!C:\Python\python.exe


import requests
import webbrowser
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
 

vin=form.getvalue('searchbox')
token='withheld'

dr=requests.get("withheld" % (token, vin))




window_stkr=(dr.json()["car"]["sticker"]["pdf"])
#webbrowser.open_new_tab(window_stkr)
print('Content-type:text/html\n\n')
print('<html>')
print('  <head>')
print('    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='+str(window_stkr)+'" />') 
print('  </head>')
print('</html>')
```